# Ansible single-element list breaks lookup call

Tags: python, ansible

I want to lookup-replace multiple lines, with a loop, in the `known_hosts` file for further SSH use. So I'm checking the file with this task:

```
- name: Checking "known_hosts"
  loop: "{{ groups['nodes'] }}"
  lineinfile:
    dest: ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    state: present
    line: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan -trsa -p 22 ' + item) }}"
    create: yes
```

This produces an error:

> Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: [u'node.env1']'. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup.

It happens to be a list of one element. Well, okay, let's edit ~

```
line: "{{ q('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan -trsa -p 22 ' + item) }}"
```

> Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: [u'node.env1']'. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup.

Thanks for the hint, Ansible-sama.

(Just in case, same behavior with `query`, or with `wantList=True`.)

What is happening here?

Comment: Using `to_json` will transform a list into a string...which is exactly the error you show. If you want to loop over a list, you *cannot* pass it to `to_json`, because then you no longer have a list. Fix your playbook, and if it doesn't work, update your question to show the relevant error.

Comment: @larsks Updated to match.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the behavior you've described in your question.  I'm using Ansible 2.9.0. If I start with this inventory in `hosts.yml`:

```
---
all:
  children:
    nodes:
      hosts:
        node.env1:
```

And this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: checking "known_hosts"
      loop: "{{ groups['nodes'] }}"
      lineinfile:
        dest: ./known_hosts
        state: present
        line: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'echo ' + item) }}"
        create: true
```

I get the following output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [checking "known_hosts"] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=node.env1)

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And the generated `known_hosts` file looks like this:

```
node.env1
```

---

If you're using the legacy INI-style inventory format rather than the YAML inventory format, then the following inventory would behave the same way as the YAML inventory at the top of this answer:

```
[nodes]

node.env1
```

Comment: I'm using Ansible 2.8.5, and cannot consider upgrading. But I'll assume this is not the problem. I'm using the INI format, and you tell me this is not what matters. So I can't see any difference from what you did to what I did ...

Comment: What happens if you run the example I've given here, with the example ini-format inventory?  I've repeated this test with Ansible versions 2.8.5 and 2.7.13 (using both inventory formats), and it seems to work in all cases without error.

Comment: I used exactly this inventory, I even changed mine which had one less carriage return.

Comment: That's very strange. I'd be happy to take a closer look, but I would need to be able to reproduce the problem. If you were able to reproduce this in a Docker image I could take a look at that, but otherwise I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I will try as soon as I can. Thanks for your time.